# how to declare variable as public const in angular 8

Tags: angular8

I wanted to declare a constant variable like this `public const SHIPMENT_MENU_ITEM='SHIPMENT';`and use in my html by referring the const variable. But I am not able to do it. What I am missing here.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header-bar',
  templateUrl: './header-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header-bar.component.scss']
})


export class HeaderBarComponent {

  activeLink: String = 'SHIPMENT';

  constructor() {

  }

  onSelectNav(option) {
    this.activeLink = option;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header-bar',
  templateUrl: './header-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header-bar.component.scss']
})


export class HeaderBarComponent {

public SHIPMENT_MENU_ITEM: String= SHIPMENT';

  activeLink: String = 'SHIPMENT';

  constructor() {

  }

  onSelectNav(option) {
    this.activeLink = option;
  }

}
```

Comment: it state public can not be declared inside class